# Grafana Helm Chart on AWS EKS, using --set for multiple service annotations

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

The grafana helm chart spawns a service on a Classic Load Balancer. I have the AWS load balancer webhook installed, and I'd like to overwrite the annotations on the Grafana service. I'm attempting the following:

```
helm install grafana grafana/grafana \
--namespace grafana \
--set persistence.storageClassName="gp2" \
--set persistence.enabled=true \
--set adminPassword='abc' \
--values grafana.yaml \
--set service.type=LoadBalancer \
--set nodeSelector.app=prometheus \
--set nodeSelector.k8s-app=metrics-server \
--set service.annotations."service\.beta.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type"=ip \
--set service.annotations."service\.beta.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-type"=external
```

but, after trying multiple permutations, I continue to get:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: YAML parse error on grafana/templates/service.yaml: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field .metadata.annotations of type string
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an issue in the annotation, you are missing  escape character for `beta\.kubernetes`

try this and it should work.

```
--set service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type"=ip \
--set service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/aws-load-balancer-type"=external
```

Comment: It's been a long day, thank you so much.